# Prove whether it is a homomorphism.

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-homomorphism, quaternions

Let $\varphi:Q_8 \to S_4$ where $\varphi(i)=(ab)$ and $\varphi(j)= (cd)$.Then is this a homomorphism? I think it is because all the conditions for homomorphisms are satisfied. Now one more homomorphism is from $Q_8$ to the klein-four group in $S_4$.The trivial homomorphism is one more case.Are these all?

Comment: \to will get you $\to$.

Comment: There are homomorphisms $Q_8\to S_4$ with image of order $2$.

Comment: How about $\psi(i)=(ac)$, $\psi(j)=(bd)$?

Comment: Anything to say, Guria?